# AngularJS Custom Attribute Name Issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJS and i was trying out AngularJS Behaviors with custom element attributes. I have this weird situation when i changed the name of the attribute i created. My initial code was like this.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div enter="panel" leave>Content</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
app.directive('enter', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('mouseenter', function() {
                element.addClass(attrs.enter); // <- I have put a breakpoint here for inspection
            });
        }
    }
});

app.directive('leave', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('mouseleave', function() {
                element.removeClass(attrs.enter);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see the attribute name that triggers the behavior is `enter` and this works as expected by adding the class `panel` to the `div`. (The breakpoints is hit when debugging) But the problem occurs when i try to change the name of the attribute to a more meaningful one.

Now the modified code..

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div onEnterAddCss="panel" leave>Content</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
app.directive('onEnterAddCss', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('mouseenter', function() {
                element.addClass(attrs.onEnterAddCss); // <- Breakpont here is never hit.
            });
        }
    }
});

app.directive('leave', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('mouseleave', function() {
                element.removeClass(attrs.onEnterAddCss);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Now when i change the attribute name to `onEnterAddCss` this does not work. The breakpoint never get hit. I am confused. Is there a specific character length that an attribute can be? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all other attributes with Angular (such as directives), you need to changed it to lower cases and dashes:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div on-enter-add-css="panel" leave>Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to how angular normalized attribute names.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
scroll down to Normalization.

It is essentially looking for an attribute named on-enter-add-css

Answer (score 1):

It is related to camelCase, in html your attribute : **on-enter-add-css** not **onEnterAddCss**

[angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)